# CSS3 animations not working in IE or Opera

Tags: internet-explorer, browser, css, opera

I created a simple animation to spin an image on a website using webkit properties and CSS3.

Here the style css (it applys only to divs)

```
.bg {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    display:block;
    -webkit-animation: spin 100s infinite linear;
    -moz-animation: spin 100s infinite linear;
    -o-animation: spin 100s infinite linear;
    -ms-animation: spin 100s infinite linear;
    opacity:0.8;
    filter:alpha(opacity=80); /* For IE8 and earlier */
    z-index:-1;
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    0% { -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-o-keyframes spin {
    0% { -o-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% { -o-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
    0% { -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);}
  100% { -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);}
}
```

Now the result is that on Mozilla Firefox, Chrome and Safari, it works without problems, but in Opera and Internet explorer I can't see any animation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation

IE10 and Opera 12 support CSS animations. Not earlier.

Comment: Hi I am using the last Opera version, downloaded as per testing

Comment: The most recent stable version of Opera is 11.62, and you need fresh build of version 12 to test animations (as they are only implemented 2 weeks ago - http://my.opera.com/desktopteam/blog/2012/03/26/html5-css-64bit). Warning: this build is extremely unstable. I guess you'll need to wait for a month or so.

Comment: @AntonioColella I've just [downloaded](http://www.opera.com/browser/next/) and [tested](http://jsfiddle.net/9pQgB/) Opera 12, and keyframed animations **are** supported.

Comment: For IE10 you need Windows 8 Customer Preview.

Comment: Hey I cannot rate your opinion, but You are wrong. CSS3 is fully supported from IE and Opera http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/hh393506.aspx as an example. Please, this is not Yahoo Answers...

Comment: @AntonioColella For Opera, see my previous comment (I've really verified it!). Regarding your IE (MSDN) link: That is **not** a CSS3 animation. CTRL+F "keyframe" -> Not found. [**This**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673530(v=vs.85).aspx) is the proper MSDN source for CSS3 animations, which state that only IE10+ support this feature.

Comment: @Rob W ok but the link I sent you is called "Internet Explorer 9 Guide for developers and I can read (regard the code I wrote):"Internet Explorer 9 adds support for CSS3 2D Transforms. CSS 2D Transforms enables elements that are rendered by CSS to be transformed in two-dimensional space.
Internet Explorer 9 supports the following 2D Transforms properties:
The -ms-transform property applies one or more two-dimensional transformation function to an element.
The -ms-transform-origin property establishes the origin of transformation for an element..." Where is stated that it's only for IE10+ ?

Comment: @AntonioColella **Transformations are not animations**. Transformations are static: Eg. an element is turned 90 degrees (without animating). Animations, on the other hand, are dynamic: The element smoothly moves to a new state. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/transform vs https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/CSS_animations.

Comment: ok Thank you! now it's clear, I have to wait a little to use:) Thank you! And sorry for my ignorance!>> :P " Please, this is not Yahoo Answers..."

Comment: I am using Opera 12.16 and my animation not work. Work in webkit and moz browsers.

Comment: @ArthurYakovlev Did you declare an unprefixed version of `@keyframes` and `animation`? If not, declare it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this information will be usefull for some one who have problems with animations in Opera 12.

In opera 12.x css animation property 'infinite' didn't works for me.
Animation was palyed only once and then stoped.
But after I changed integer value of duration (for example 1s) to fractional value (for example 1.1s) animatione start play infinite.